# Не могу изменить размеры дочерней формы в MDI

Tags: delphi

Не могу изменить размеры дочерней формы. Пишу разные варианты:

```
Fchild.Height:=Fmain.ClientHeight;
Fchild.Height:=Fmain.Height;
Fchild.Height:=700;
```

но никак,Fchild.height=994.

```
Formstyle=MDIChild;
Windowstate=maximized or Normal;
BorderStyle=пробовал Sizeable,Dialog,None,Single
```

в чем может быть причина? 
проблема как-то связана с главной формой- Fmain.height=1014, а Fchild.height=994  без изменения.

Comment: попробуйте дочерней форме в дизайн тайме выставить `position` в `poDefaultPosOnly`.

Comment: @teran так и есть, но ничего не меняет.

Comment: с другими значениями тоже не работает?

Comment: все варианты пробовал.

Comment: Не понял откуда берет цифру 994

Comment: ну могу вам посоветовать в таком случае включить отладочные dcu-файлы и углубиться в недра VCL начав отладку на присвоении `Height` формы, там и выясните, почему размер не изменяется.

Comment: вопрос в целом следует закрыть или удалить, ибо по сути дубликат. Я вам в соседнем вопросе ответил.

Answer (score 0):

Уверены ли, что тут именно нужен MDI?
Если нет, возможно будет достаточно

```
Fchild.Parent := Fmain;
Fchild.Align := alClient;
Fchild.BorderStyle := bsNone;
```

Comment: дак человек MDI приложение если разрабатывает

Comment: Если нужно оставить заголовок дочернего окна, то можно не писать

Fchild.BorderStyle := bsNone; судя по дублирующему вопросу "дочерная форма не польностью помещается в клиентскую часть главной формы" не вижу зачем тут MDI

Comment: судя по комментариям в соседнем вопросе, вы были таки правы :)

Comment: @Sergey Amelin MDI точно нужен. 
align и так alClient, 
BorderStyle никак не вляет на результат.

Comment: @teran в OnCreate пока вызывал процедуру MDIChildCreated: 
procedure TMainForm.MDIChildCreated(const childHandle : THandle);
var i:integer;
begin
  mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.AddObject(TForm(FindControl(childHandle)).Caption, TObject(childHandle));
  mdiChildrenTabs.TabIndex := -1 + mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.Count;
end; 
а потом Fchild.Height:=.....
поменял местами и уже меняю размеры формы. :) 
Хотя не понял почему!